# Run .NetCore App in docker container based on .NETCore 3.0 preview

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, console-application

**On running my app exited with code** `150`

> Output: Debug

---

```
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.0-preview3-27503-5' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /usr/share/dotnet/
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      3.0.0-preview-27324-5 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[31] dotnet' has exited with code 150 (0x96).
The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 150 (0x96).
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sometime someday

Comment: @AndrewDzhur right now would be a good time. Bad questions get closed and deleted pretty quickly. In this case, the question is missing completely

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems running the application in the **Docker Container**, then make sure that the correct **Image** for your **.NET Core SDK** is specified in the **Dockerfile**

For the **.NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview3-010431**

**Dockerfile** was created incorrectly.
You can view **Dockerfile** samples for various **SDKs** at ***hub.docker.com***

> https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/?tab=description

Example:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm

# Install .NET CLI dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libc6 \
        libgcc1 \
        libgssapi-krb5-2 \
        libicu57 \
        libssl1.1 \
        libstdc++6 \
        zlib1g \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 3.0.100-preview3-010431
```

...

Comment: What does this answer? And why would the docker image contain the *SDK*? It only needs the runtime. If you create a self-contained application, not even that. The runtime will be included in the deployment package

Comment: I wrote the answer quite accurately. It clearly states that the image would be suitable for the SDK on which your project is based. it would be better if you read it again and did not write comments

Comment: The question was downvoted heavily for a reason - there is no question. As for the answer, if you check, you'll see that you don't need the *SDK* to run .NET Core applications, only the *runtime*. If you asked `What SDK version should I add to a production Docker image?` the correct answer would be `None, you only need the runtime`.  Your answer would be accurate if the question was `What SDK version should I add to a build server Docker image?`